# (Python) How can I print the function name of a partial function

Tags: python, partial, functools

I am running a process where I add failed functions to a list to be retried later. I use partial for this. Now I want to print what function is being retried.

#### Example Code:

```
retry_queue = []

def foo():
    """ Try and run function_a """

    result = function_a()

    if !result:
        retry_queue.append(partial(function_a, args)

    return retry_queue


# run the foo function
foo()

# retry all the failed functions
for function in retry_queue:
    print("Now running function: %s", function)
    function()


Wanted output:

>>> Now running function: function_a
```

How can I change my code to produce the wanted result?

I tried printing the example code, but that just gave a pointer to an object of the function.

Comment: `print("Now running function: %s", function.__name__)`I believe, would do the trick, assuming you don't error out on that unclosed parentheses in your `retry_queue.append()` line.

Comment: `function.func.__name__` maybe? You can access the underlying function object from a [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) object with the `.func` attribute.

Comment: Naive `function.__name__` will not do the trick. `functools.partial` is a different object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the original function with the `func` attribute. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial.func) for more information.

In case you pass regular functions, you should write a wrapper that extracts the name of partial objects or "normal" functions.

```
from functools import partial
from typing import Callable, Any

def callable_name(any_callable: Callable[..., Any]) -> str:
    if isinstance(any_callable, partial):
        return any_callable.func.__name__

    try:
        return any_callable.__name__
    except AttributeError:
        return str(any_callable)
```

Now `callable_name(print)` and `callable_name(partial(print, "Hello,"))` both return `'print'`.

If you have to support other callables besides `partial` and functions, you can add cases to handle that.

Comment: This is still pretty fragile. There are more callable types than just `function` and `partial`. `__name__` is a special case of the `function` type, not something you can generally assume is available.

Comment: True, i will add a default case

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to make a custom partial function to wrap your function to it, then you can use `__name__`:

```py
from functools import partial, update_wrapper
retry_queue = []


def wrapped_partial(func, *args, **kwargs):
    partial_func = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    update_wrapper(partial_func, func)
    return partial_func

def function_a(args = 1):
    return None

def foo():
    """ Try and run function_a """
    result = function_a()
    args = 1
    if not result:
        retry_queue.append(wrapped_partial(function_a, args))
    return retry_queue


# run the foo function
foo()

# retry all the failed functions
for function in retry_queue:
    print("Now running function: " + function.__name__)
    function()
```

Output: `Now running function: function_a`